# python nose how to set dynamic --xunit-file name

Tags: python, nose, xunit

how to set the `--xunit-file` so that the result file is named after the test script's name and current dir name?

I'm running my test like this:

```
[dir_name]$ nosetests --with-xunit --xunit-file=???? test/test_file_name.py
```

Idealy, the xml can be named after `dir_name` and `test_file_name`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I put together:

1) since I'm doing this in shell script, so I have access to the string `test/test_file_name.py`. I set `--xunit-file=` according to my test script's name

2) post-processing I: prefix the `dir_name` to the xml file

3) post-processing II: in each xml file, modify all the `classname="class_name"` to include the `dir_name`, like this, `classname="dir_name_class_name`

The last step is necessary since I found out only modifying the xml file names doesn't work. To display the results correctly (in Jenkins), all the class names need to be modified as well.